# How to separate floats from strings

Tags: python, string, list, file, physics

I have a tab delaminated txt file.  One of the columns includes floats and then strings. I would like to NOT include everything after the strings. So instead of the lum list looking like .25+1,.47-4... my list would just have .25,.47 ...

[image]
[[image]

Obviously right now my error reads "could not convert string to float: '.25+1"

any suggestions?

EDIT

```
f=open('C:/Users/clark/OneDrive/Desktop/Tests/test_big.txt',"r")
lines=f.readlines()
for x in lines:
    name.append         ((x.split('\t')[0]))
    phi.append          (float(x.split('\t')[1]))
    theta.append        (float(x.split('\t')[2]))           #append approperiate values to the empty sets
    hubble_D.append     (float(x.split('\t')[3]))
    Type.append         ((x.split('\t')[4]))
    lum.append          (float(x.split('\t')[5]))
    bt_ratio.append     (float(x.split('\t')[6]))
f.close()
```

Comment: One way would be to match with a regular expression, but probably easier is to search for '+' or '-' and trim the string there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Picture are very poor format to exchange textual data. Please update you post with a [mcve] where those data are copy pasted in a parsable format. No screenshot.

Comment: Also, don't call "split" 7 times.  Call it once and assign the pieces to variables, like `parts = x.split('\t')`.

Comment: Do you expect values like "-.25+6"? Or are relevant values always in the 0 - 1 range?

Comment: no, they are ratios so 0-1 range @Grismar

Answer (score 1):

You can easily take the value `".25+1"` and use its .split() function for both `'+'` and `'-'` then just use the first value in the list like so

```
val = '.25+1'
parts = val.split('+' if '+' in val else '-')
print(parts[0]) #Output is """ .25 """
```

or, if there are other characters in the string than a + or -, you can create a new string while iterating over each character like this:

```
val = '.25+1'
newString = ''
for char in val:
    if not char.isdigit() and char != '.': break
    newString += char
print(float(newString)) #Output is """ .25 """
```

Answer (score 1):

in future, please, use raw text (copy past) not screenshots.

---

```
lum = []
f = open('.\\test_big.txt')
lines = f.readlines()

for x in lines:
    data = x.split('\t')

    if '+' in data[5]:
        part01 = data[5].split('+')
        final_value = float(part01[0])

    if '-' in data[5]:
        # one line
        final_value = float(data[5].split('-')[0])

    lum.append(final_value)

print(lum)
```

Output: [0.25, 0.47, ...]